# Is there any way to set default isolation level of EF Code First(earlier versions than 6) to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

According this [link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs&ANCHOR) in Entity Framework web site, default transaction isolation level of EF6 changes to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

> Default transaction isolation level is changed to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT for databases created using Code First, potentially allowing for more scalability and fewer deadlocks.

Is there any way to set default transaction isolation level of EF(Code First) earlier versions to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`?